# Best way to embed graphs (Data visualization) in my PyQt5 GUI (Non-Web Based application)

Tags: user-interface, embed, pyqt5, pygal

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to coding sorry if this question is basic.

I'm currently making a program that takes some measurements and formats the data into a csv file. Now I want to be able to plot those measurements in an application I'm making in PyQt5.

I've been looking around for a library that I can use to plot the data. Something that I can embed in my application and doesn't require an online dependency.

I looked into to pygal, but the problem with pygal is that it uses svg files that require an internet connection or it saves the graphs to a png.

I want to be able to present the data in my application window, give the user an option interact and adjust the data within my window, and then choose to save the graphic or not.

I'm not sure if this is true or not, but the libraries (plotly, bokeh) I have looked at so far have been aimed at web development apps and sites, that are embedded using html. I'm just wondering If I can embed these libraries as offline versions in my GUI.

And if it's possible to use pygal in my app what's the syntax to add the graphs to my layout look like?

Comment: Take a look at [pyqtgraph](http://pyqtgraph.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to show html/javascript/svg in PyQt5 you can use pygal offline.

use the method

`chart.render()`

to fetch the SVG, and replace "{pygal_render}" it in the following html string with the SVG.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/svg.jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/pygal-tooltips.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
      {pygal_render}
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
```

To have it offline, download the JS files and put in in the head in script tags instead of linking it.